# Javascript retrive option of a select set without a class or id

Tags: javascript, wordpress, select

Hi I have the following code and try to retrieve the selected option of a list(for example Myoption2) created without a class or an id like the following:

```
<div class="form-group" data-type="service">
    <label>Mylabel</label>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option value="0">MyOption1</option>
            <option value="12">MyOption2</option>
            <option value="17">MyOption3</option>
            <option value="18">MyOption4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I didn't find the proper way to get this work with queryselector :[

This code is generated automatically by a wordpress plugin. So I didn't find an easy way to edit it and define a class or an id.

Thank's in advance for your help.

Comment: What did you try? Also, is that div the ONLY div with `data-type="service"` or are there more than one? I guess I'm asking if there is anything unique about the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

First, you attach the 'onchange' event to your select tag:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].setAttribute( "onchange", "getValue(this)" );
```

Then you define this function, which is triggered once you change your select item:

```
function getValue(selectObject) {
  var e = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;
  alert(e)
}
```